# MySQLi Query 2 tables based on count form one table over 30 days

Tags: php, join, mysqli, group-by

I am having a trouble with a query.

I need to collect 2 companies from trade_directory where they have status 1 and match 3 categories.

I want to select the 2 companies on the least view first basis counted from company_views within the last 30 days.

```
SELECT
    b.id, b.v_date, b.c_id COUNT(b.c_id) AS v_count
    AND b.v_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY) 
FROM
    company_views b
    LEFT JOIN trade_directory v ON v.id = b.c_id
WHERE
    v.cat1 = 'cat'  
    AND v.cat2 = 'rat'  
    AND v.cat3 = 'hat'                          
    AND v.status = '1'
GROUP BY
    b.c_id
ORDER BY
    v_count ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You're using `AND` operator in `SELECT` instead of `WHERE`

```
AND b.v_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY)
```

can your try this code

```
SELECT
    b.id, b.v_date, b.c_id COUNT(b.c_id) AS v_count
FROM
    company_views b
    LEFT JOIN trade_directory v ON v.id = b.c_id
WHERE
    v.cat1 = 'cat'  
    AND v.cat2 = 'rat'  
    AND v.cat3 = 'hat'                          
    AND v.status = '1'
    AND b.v_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY) 
GROUP BY
    b.c_id
ORDER BY
    v_count ASC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried this and it's not behaving as I need, I found this quote "You had a LEFT JOIN but the later WHERE conditions forced it to be a plain JOIN." so the AND part needs to stay where it is apparently!

I changed my approach (using different tables but here it what is working but it is really really slow)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach (using different tables but here it what is working but it is **really really slow**)

```
SELECT o.*, COUNT(e.c_id) AS b_count
                    FROM cat3_entries o
                    LEFT JOIN company_views e ON e.c_id = o.c_id 
                        AND e.v_date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY)
                    WHERE
                        o.c3_id = '81'                          
                    GROUP BY
                        o.c_id
                    ORDER BY
                        b_count ASC
                    LIMIT
                        3;
```

If I could resolve the speed issue this one would be great.

Comment: you are selecting all columns from `cat3_entries o` instead of `o.*` only include columns which you require